# How to deserialize xml with nested lists?

Tags: java, xml, spring, jackson, jaxb

How can I read an xml response containing nested lists?
The following does not work, means the nested list is always empty. Why?

```
    JacksonXmlModule xmlMod = new JacksonXmlModule();
    xmlMod.setDefaultUseWrapper(false);

    ObjectMapper m = (new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder())
            .createXmlMapper(true)
            .modules(xmlMod, new JaxbAnnotationModule())
            .build();


    PersonResponse rsp = m.readValue(ReaderUtil.read("person.xml"), PersonResponse.class)

//all fields having getter + setter, omitted for readability
@XmlRootElement
public class PersonResponse {
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    private Persons persons;

    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    public static class Persons {
        @XmlElement(required = true)
        List<Person> person;

        @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
        public static class Person {
            @XmlAttribute(name="firstname", required=true)
            private String firstname;
        }
    }
}
```

person.xml:

```
<response>
    <persons>
        <person firstname="test" />
        <person firstname="john" />
    </persons>
</response>
```

Result: the `person` list is always empty inside the response object. Why?

Comment: You might be missing an ``@XmlElement`` before ``private Persons persons;``

Comment: That's just a typo here in the question, corrected it.

Comment: I couldn't find an answer (without insisting too much to my tastes). At this point, I'd start to think that when I want to use Jackson, I should do it with Jackson annotations, and when I want to use JAXB annotations, I should do it with JAXB. That's kind of their points. Sure, it doesn't seem like an impossibility for them to deal nicely with each other, but why not just going the simple way?

Comment: The reason is: I'm using autogeneration to create the `PersonResponse` from an `XSD`, with the `maven` plugin `cxf-xjc-plugin`. As far as I know, there is no existing autogeneration plugin that would add `Jackson` annotations (correct me if I'm wrong). Only `JAXB` annotations can be autogenerated. But as I want to use the jackson `ObjectMapper` for several reasons, I have to stick to `jaxb` annotations though and teach him jaxb annotations by using the `JaxbAnnotationModule`.